# 500 error when select clob field in oracle 11g

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, oracle11g

When iam running my oracle query showing 500 error in server. The error showing when selecting clob field in oracle query.The field contains big json data

Error is:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error C:\php7.0.3\php-cgi.exe - The
>   FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

**here my query:**

```
SELECT knowyour.*,
  kp.personal_details AS personal_details,
  kp.fullname,
  kcd.category,
  kcd.ID AS kycID
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT kc.kyc_reffer_id,
    kc.ID,
    kc.customer_id,
    kc.json_details AS json_details,
    kc.customer_joint_id,
    kc.customer_id AS kycCustomer_id
  FROM db.knwcustomer kc
  ) knowyour
INNER JOIN db.createdetails kcd
ON (knowyour.customer_id=kcd.customer_id)
INNER JOIN db.personaldetails kp
ON (knowyour.kyc_reffer_id=kp.kyc_reffer_id)
LEFT JOIN db.kaccountdetails kd
ON (knowyour.customer_id=kd.customer_id)

WHERE kcd.displayStatus!=:status
AND kcd.category=:category
AND kd.status!=:status
AND kp.status!=:status
AND kcd.client_id=:client_id
ORDER BY kcd.ID
```

here status = -1

**(query running in php pdo)**

This is an example query.

personal_details and json_details are clob fields.Distinct will not work when selecting clob field that's why Iam using this query method.

is this code problem or server problem? But this code is working perfectly in my local wamp server not in online server.

I need help !

Comment: Check the PHP error log. It should show the root cause.

Comment: php error log showed nothing... :(

Comment: "is this code problem or server problem?". You'll need to determine that via debugging. Hopefully you have access to a proper debugger such as [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/). Otherwise you need to use `var_dump()` and `exit` to check each line of your code and isolate where the problem occurs.

Comment: I checked my each code line with var_dump and then exit. i found that when I remove clob fields from select it will work otherwise 500 http error will come. @timclutton

Comment: You haven't included your PHP so I'll just assume you've correctly followed the documentation about using [LOBs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php)...

Comment: You mean php version? its 7.0.3.   "select dbms_lob.substr(json_details,4000) from db.kncustomer" only this will work .. but i need all datas not only 4000 char.. "select json_details from db.kncustomer" is working in my local wamp server not in online server.

Comment: No I mean your PHP _code_ that isn't working. Edit your post to include it.

Comment: that query is just an example i will edit my query check..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using php with PDO then try set attribute as below

```
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES,TRUE);
```

This will convert all columns to strings, regardless of their original type and  this does not include NULL columns ,and does not translate data being inserted.
By setting this, it will be same behavior as mysql even fetching from oracle.

Comment: Now clob field working like normal field :) .. Thanx shafeeq bhai :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried querying only one clob field from concrete table?

Like:

```
SELECT CLOB_FIELD 
FROM EX_TABLE;
```

If this will work, there is probably a problem in a query itself. Your query is complex enough to hide some issues.

Comment: yes this also showing same 500 error :(      "select json_details from db.kncustomer "

Comment: "select dbms_lob.substr(json_details,4000) from db.kncustomer" only this will work .. but i need all datas not only 4000 char.. "select json_details from db.kncustomer" is working in my local wamp server not in online server. thats why iam confused !

Comment: Hm. This is wierd. It seems like the server cannot provide clob. But it can manipulate with it. It seems like a server problem.